# Macro that Hides Rows Doesn't Update When Named Range Changes Sizes

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I compiled some code that hides rows based on some certain criteria. At the beginning of the code, I unhide all the rows so that when the sheet recalculates the correct rows hide. Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim primaryarray As Range
Dim rw As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Experience Rating Sheet")
Set primaryarray = ws.Range("B9:M322")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' unhide all rows before we begin
primaryarray.EntireRow.Hidden = False

For Each rw In primaryarray.Rows
    rw.EntireRow.Hidden = BlankOrZero(rw.Cells(4)) And BlankOrZero(rw.Cells(8))
Next rw

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Function BlankOrZero(c As Range)
BlankOrZero = Len(c.Value) = 0 Or c.Value = 0
End Function
```

The range that it is checking is a named range that shows

```
=IF(Expected_Actual_Losses="","",Expected_Actual_Losses)
```

in order to get rid of random zeros.

I have to manually press the the calculate worksheet each time to fix it because the calculation is on manual.

I have tried putting `Worksheet.Calculate` in the Module to compensate for this but it has not worked.

By compensate, I mean automate this calculation in order to change how many rows are hidden.

Note: The source for the named range is also 2 different sections that have dynamic formulas that change sizes based on criteria I set. Using index/match for one and filter/sortby formulas for the other.

Comment: That won't work because the code only runs when the sheet is calculated .... Why is calculation set to manual?

Comment: Perhaps use another event.

Comment: because I have a lot of complicated and dynamic formulas that auto-recalculate every time i click on something in the workbook.  what event would you suggest?  I have an "update workbook" loop that calculates all of the necessary worksheets including the one that the above code is linked to.

Comment: Is that `Worksheet_Calculate` code in the sheet module for "Experience Rating Sheet", or some other sheet module ?

Comment: A named Range is actually a named formula. It does not store a calculated value - its formula gets calculated each time a cell formula that uses the named range is calculated, but the value from the Named range only gets returned to the formula that called it.

Comment: @TimWilliams it is in that sheet module.

Comment: OK that confused me a bit - inside a worksheet module you can just use `Me` to refer to the sheet itself. Eg:  `Set primaryarray = Me.Range("B9:M322")`

Comment: Shouldn't this line: Set primaryarray = ws.Range("B9:M322") reference your Dynamic Range Name vs the fixed reference?

Comment: @CharlesWilliams, because it IS a formula we cant use the `Change` event. How do you suggest I get it to update automatically?

Comment: @RetiredGeek The named range is on a separate sheet so hiding/unhiding rows doesn't work across sheets. You have to cater the hiding/unhiding to specific sheet you are wanting the hiding/unhiding to happen.

Comment: Should I make a loop that unhides each row individually? instead of `primaryarray.EntireRow.Hidden = False`

Answer (score 0):

PotterFan,

I beg to differ, the following code has no problem hiding/unhiding rows on a non-active sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideFilter(lFilter As Long)

   Dim wksHide As Worksheet
   Dim lCntr As Long
   Dim lFirstRow As Long
   Dim lLastRow As Long
  
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'Just to make sure not running from Sheet2!
   
   Set wksHide = Sheets("Sheet2")
   
   lFirstRow = Range("HideRange").Row  'Return 1st row
   lLastRow = (Range("HideRange").Count - 1) + lFirstRow
   
   wksHide.Range("HideRange").EntireRow.Hidden = False
   
   For lCntr = lLastRow To lFirstRow Step -1
   
      If wksHide.Cells(lCntr, 1).Value = lFilter Then wksHide.Cells(lCntr, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
      
   Next lCntr
   
End Sub
```

Before:

[image: Before running code, notice lines 2,4,6 hidden.]

After:

[image]

Comment: I had no idea I could reference a named range in VBA. So could I use this code to automatically hide/unhide rows as the named range changes size?  Also I am not sure I understand the logic of the For Loop.

Comment: Yes, but you'll need a Worksheet_Change event to monitor the changes in the dynamic range and trigger the code.

Comment: was your code just a different way of hiding the rows and i just change the reference and the event trigger? or would it be better I switch to your code?

Comment: So I changed the trigger event and the range to named range but it is still not updating automatically.

Comment: Any way you can post a sanitized version of your workbook?

Comment: it is too complicated to try to sanitize.  I just tried and excel corrupted the file. hmm... what were you looking for maybe I can find and explain it?

Comment: I wanted to be able to see the whole setup. Name definitions, macros, sheet layout, etc.

Comment: How would you implement the above code that you provided into an event_Calculate format? I want to try it to see if that works.

Comment: I'm not sure without more context.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when I tried to calculate the worksheet on my other macro it was in-between an `Application.EnableEvents` command so the `Worksheet_Calculate` wouldn't trigger when it was supposed to. Here is the other Macro:

```
Sub UpdateReport()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Puts in the effective date and member name
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Report As Variant
Dim xprating As Variant

Set Report = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Yearly Breakdown", "Loss Template", "Codes", "Yearly Breakdown", "Cover Sheet", "Ag Loss Sensitivity", "Experience Rating Sheet", "Loss Ratio Analysis", "Mod Analysis&Strategy Proposal", "Mod Snapshot", "Mod & Potential Savings"))
Set xprating = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Experience Rating Sheet")

For Each ws In Report
    ws.Calculate
Next ws

For Each ws In Report
    ws.Calculate
    ws.PageSetup.RightFooter = Sheet17.Range("B3").Text & Chr(10) & "Mod Effective Date:     " & Sheet17.Range("B4")
Next ws

Application.EnableEvents = True

xprating.Calculate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I just stuck `xprating.Calculate` after `Application.EnableEvents = True` and it started updating the rows automatically.